# os.rename gives [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Tags: python, csv

Good day,
 I have as python script that cycles through directories on looks in CSV for certain variables and then rename them according to those variables. Everything works fine up to the rename when I get a [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: error. Closed all applications but still getting error. Thanks in advance

**CODE:**

```
import os

import csv

print(os.getcwd()) # check to see current directory

os.chdir('\\DataLoad\\Qualities\\Aug-2018') 

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):   

    for filename in filenames: # print path to all filenames.

        if filename[-3:] == 'csv':  
            print(os.path.join(filename)) # (os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            file_name = os.path.join(filename)

            with open(file_name, newline='') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                header = next(reader) # reads first line of csv - HEADER line
                row1 = f.readlines()[1]
                borehole = row1.split(',')[3].upper()

                if header[13] == 'Yield':
                    NewFile = 'WASH_' + borehole + '.csv'
                    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)

                elif header[13] == 'Min S':
                    NewFile = 'SPECIAL_' + borehole + '.csv'
                    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)
                elif header[13] == 'Ad TS':
                    NewFile = 'PROX_' + borehole + '.csv'
                    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)
                else:
                    NewFile = 'OTHER_' + borehole + '.csv'
                    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)
```

Comment: something is probably using the file in background. Restart your system and try running the code again.

Comment: @serbia99 the script itself has an open handle to the file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
with open(file_name, newline='') as f
```

and inside that block you have

```
    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)
```

so your script itself has an open handle on the file you are trying to rename which is why you get the error.

Since the reading of the file is finished before the `if` statements, you could unindent them to have them outside the `with` block:

```
with open(file_name, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader) # reads first line of csv - HEADER line
    row1 = f.readlines()[1]
    borehole = row1.split(',')[3].upper()

if header[13] == 'Yield':
    NewFile = 'WASH_' + borehole + '.csv'
    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)

elif header[13] == 'Min S':
    NewFile = 'SPECIAL_' + borehole + '.csv'
    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)
elif header[13] == 'Ad TS':
    NewFile = 'PROX_' + borehole + '.csv'
    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)
else:
    NewFile = 'OTHER_' + borehole + '.csv'
    os.rename(file_name, NewFile)
```